# Why is this camping question considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just discovered this site when a question here...

[What are my options for accommodation whilst travelling by bicycle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13174/345)

...was closed and [migrated to Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/14293/8). (I saw the question there.) Unfortunately, it was closed on Bicycles as well. (It's unclear if camping is on-topic there on its own, but I suspect that it's not.)

My question: Why is this question off-topic here? I see that camping is [on-topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/82/345) here, is there another reason? Also, how much does this site overlap with [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) on camping questions?

(I'm not complaining about the closure, I'd just like to understand.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We try not to have too broad questions on Travel.SE. That particular question was asking about cycling + camping trips without defining any a specific list of geographical areas the OP was concerned with.

I was in two minds about either closing the question outright for being 'too broad' or migrating it to Bicycles.SE, since they might have had better general advice on how to deal with biking on long tours. As I mentioned, the question is too broad and vague, and hence it seems it was closed there too.

There's a definite overlap between the three sites, so I guess it boils down to which component of the question is most important: cycling, travel, or camping.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that a tighter focused question would have been on-topic here!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.